# Sublime Text sidebar scroll plugin

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a Sublime Text plugin that will always show my current file in the sidebar?

I've found the packaged "SyncedSidebar" which seems to be a popular answer. But it doesn't really work since if you have a long list of files open, the file you are currently working on may be below the bottom of the editor. There is nothing that scrolls it into view.

Is there a plugin that will always keep the opened file scrolled into my current sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your issue is exactly... but as far as sidebar scrolling goes, I have tried your scenario, opening a ton of files, and i can scroll just fine on ST2 and ST3.

However, the plugin I use for sidebar stuff is not `SyncedSidebar`, but `SideBarEnhancements`. If you use Package Control, you can easily find it. Or you can look it up on [GitHub](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements).

Comment: I'm almost certain he means that the sidebar doesn't *automatically* scroll so that the current file is visible. I can't find a way to get it to auto-scroll either. Seems like it should be a really basic feature... Is that description of the issue clear, though?

Comment: @Owen_R I just installed SyncedSidebar and it auto scrolls the sidebar to the current file.